# What is the difference of running WAMP or XAMPP between the different versions of windows?

Tags: windows

I am going to run a small web server using WAMP or XAMPP apache. What is the difference between installing on Windows XP, Windows 7 Home Premium, Windows 7 Professional, Windows 2008 Web Edition, and Windows 2008 Standard Edition? Is there a limit on number of connection in Windows 7 that Windows 2008 doesn't have?

I don't have the resource / knowledge to run on linux, so it is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are connection limit differences between the versions/editions of Windows, and the non-server versions are deliberately limited to a very low number of concurrent inbound connections to prevent people from running a server on a non-server OS, precisely so that people who want to run a server of any size have to pay the heftier license cost for a Windows Server edition in order to do so.

So, scratch XP and 7 off the list right now, and you're left with 2008 Web Edition and 2008 Standard Edition.  Web is basically a stripped down version of Standard that doesn't have the capability to run roles other than IIS and/or DNS.  If all you're going to do is use it for a small web server, it might be worth saving a few bucks by using the Web edition, but that would not be my preference.  Either way, the most important thing is that you use a server OS, and don't try to run this off of Windows 7 or XP (or Vista or 8).

Seems the webpage for the Server 2008 edition comparison now redirects to some "buy Server 2012" BS, so all I can provide is [this link to a pdf from download.microsoft.com](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/6/FC6006B5-866E-42C1-88F8-9AC4B8BC610D/WS%20Brand%20Pages%20-%20Editions%20Comparison%20Guide.pdf) that compares available features in the different editions of Server 2008 R2.  Should be able to figure out which edition you favor from that.

Answer (score 2):

there are connection limitations in windwos XP, but your being very vague, you need to note if this for work or personal use as the answer given will be different depending.

but generally using a proper server (windows 2008 data center) is your best option for the load it can handle, but again this is dependent on what you need it for.

please see the below link for information regarding XAMMP vs wamp, but from my experiences its simply the user interface that differ with both providing more or less the same thing (MySQL, Apache)

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2171/wamp-vs-xampp-pros-cons-for-running-a-local-testing-server

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of the answer above that has been selected and upvoted, there are no artificial incoming TCP/IP connection limits on any current Windows versions *to prevent you from running a web server on a non-server OS*.

There are ONLY...

1. User login, printer, network and file sharing limits - that get wrongly confused with TCP/IP connections - that have absolutly nothing to do with Apache, IIS, or any other web server software installed on Windows.
2. Some TCP/IP Registry settings for controlling conections and rate limits... For example - some older versions of Windows were restricting the number of half-open connections allowed in any given time for security reasons, but that's either been removed, or can be patched (see - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969710).

As far as I can figure this out with research, if you are running anything at or above Vista SP2, you are unlikely to have any TCP/IP limits sets. And if they are, it's as simple as running regedit32.exe, finding the key/value, and updating it.

Comment: That's not correct.  Have you ever tried setting up an *AMP stack, or hosting a website from a desktop version of a Windows OS?  You will be unable to serve up a website to hundreds of visitors unless you use a Windows server OS.